# How do I force a route to wait for files to finish uploading from the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer, sharp

I am trying to use Sharp to shrink multiple files on the server once they are uploaded by client. The problem that I keep running in to is that the files seem to not have finished uploading by the time that Sharp attempts to access them. I keep getting a "file doesn't exist", or "unknown filetype" or some other error like that.

Here is a simple example of what I am doing:

```
app.post("/update", upload.array("images"), function(req, res){
    let promises = [];
    
    for(let i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++){
        let newImage = sharp(req.files[i].filename)
            .resize(1000, 750)
            .toFile(`/myFiles/${req.files[i].filename}.webp`)
            .catch((err)=>{
                console.error(err);
            });
            
        promises.push(newImage);
    }
    
    Promise.all(promises)
        .then((response)=>{
            //Do things
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            console.error(err);
        });
}
```

Using multer for uploads:

```
const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer({
    dest: "./uploads"
});
```

Error examples:

```
[Error: /home/leemorgan/projects/javascript/market/market-api/uploads/422d9803530522eaeba6f176a8258ec8: unable to open for read
unix error: No such file or directory
]
[Error: Input file contains unsupported image format]
```

Sometimes all of the files throw errors, sometimes none, and you never know which file will throw which error. So, I assume this is a race condition here, that the files have not finished uploading to the server yet.

How can I force the promises or the program to wait for the files to completely finish uploading before attempting to modify them?

Comment: What middleware are you using to actually read the uploaded files? Please show that code.  Express does not read them by default.

Comment: @jfriend00 Using multer for uploads. Added the code for that middleware.

Comment: Have you grabbed one of the uploaded files from your server file system and checked to see if it's a valid `.webp` file?  I don't think this is a waiting issue.  If you're using `multer()` properly, it will do the waiting before your route handler gets called.

Comment: It certainly seems valid. When Sharp runs, it works some of the time, and in that case I get the exact file that I expected. Also, I have tried using Await on Sharp, so that they don't run all at once and it seems to work every time.

Comment: Found the issue, and I'm an idiot. I was using fs.unlink() to remove the original files before I called Promise.all(), deleting the files before they were accessed/edited.

Answer (score 0):

As jfriend00 commented, multer finishes uploading the files before my handler gets called.

The problem was that I was calling fs.unlink() to remove the original files before Promise.all() had finished its business. So the file was removed before Sharp accessed/edited the file.